# How can I edit the useEffect hook in react so that whenever there is a new row in mySQL or database, the table generated will auto refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

Here is my frontend code .js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar";
import Axios from "axios"; //axios library to make requests to api
import "./Stats.css";


function Stats() {
  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []); 
  

  {/*}
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(1);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("/time")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setCurrentTime(data.time);
        });
    }, []);
  */}
    
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      <button>Show Dashboard</button>
      </div>
      <table className="customertable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S/N</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Customer Email</th>
          <th>Counts of Visit</th>
          <th>Latest Time of Visit</th>
          <th>Contacted?</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {customerList.map((val, key) => {
          const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
          const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
          const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{val.ID}</td>
              <td>{val.name}</td>
              <td>{val.email}</td>
              <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
              <td>{dateTime}</td>
              <td>{val.contacted}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        },)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Stats;
```

My specific question will be on the react useEffect hook, right now when mySQL has a new row of data, I need to manually refresh the page then the table will be generated with the new record. How can I edit the code above such that whenever there is a new insertion of a row of data into mySQL, the page will auto refresh itself so that the table will be generated?

Comment: You can add `customerList` inside the dependency array and the effect will run again each time `customerList` will update check if the effect will run indefinitely. Or you can update the state each time a new row is added and this will re-render the application, and then you can fetch the data only once and update the state from the form state.

Answer (score 0):

Add `customerList` to the dependency list in useEffect, to make the function in `useEffect` rerun everytime `customerList` changes.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, [customerList]);
```

Comment: You might need to use some kind of web hook to let react know when to re-render suffs. OR use firebase db with active snapshot listener.

Comment: hi @lacidexh, I did this but it keeps pulling the data from the api call which is what I do not want, I only want it to refresh whenever there is a change to the database. I tried your method and console.log(response) and I realize its making api calls every single second which isn't good as there is a limit to the api calls?